# Dataframe of a fixed number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to create a dataframe of a fixed number of rows, say, 100 rows.

Dataframe has following columns: datetimeindex, stock closing price, EMA5, EMA12.

When the on_ticks function runs, I append new row to it, it is pushed at the bottom, and the oldest row is discarded, keeping the size of the dataframe fixed. (all rows move up by 1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some sample data? How is possible distingusih oldest row? There is datetimeindex?

Comment: yes, it has datetimeindex. I want to push the new row in bottom and it should knock off the oldest row out of the dataframe (all rows move up by 1)

Comment: So it is last row? oldiest is last row? There are unique datetimeindex values? Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. for 5 rows?

Comment: Write a function that takes a DataFrame and a row as arguments and returns a DataFrame with the new row sans the first row - probably use a slice. ... [Different choices for indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) ... [Slicing ranges](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove first row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for remove row by positions after append new row to bottom and add [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid possible `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
df = df.iloc[1:].copy()
```

If want filter last 100 rows:

```
df = df.iloc[-100:].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your datetime index is sorted in ascending order you can do it as follows

**Creating Dummy DataFrame**

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3), columns=list("ABC"))
df.set_index(pd.date_range("oct-27-2019", periods=100, freq="min"), inplace=True)
```

**Solution**

```py
## add new row for next minute
df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name + pd.Timedelta(1, "min")] = [0.1,0.1,0.1]
## remove the oldest row in the dataframe
df.drop(index=df.iloc[0].name, inplace=True)
df
```